# Sorting ArrayList of objects according to a specific field

Tags: android, class, sorting, object, arraylist

I have a JSON file of medicines with name, ID, price, I read this file and store it in an ArrayList of Drugs, with the same fields, ID, Price, Name.
I want to sort the ArrayList ascending or descending according to the price of the drug.
all i want to know is the code to how to sort an arraylist according to a specific field
Thx

Comment: It might be worth it to just use a SQLite Database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Drug>() {
    public int compare(Drug a, Drug b) {
```

From the doc

> Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first
>   argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.